# How to make section with no bold?

Tags: table-of-contents

How i can make sections and title of `\tableofcontents`  with normal font, like subsections?

```
\documentclass[floatsubsection,equationsubsection,14pt,nocolumnsxix]{eskdtext}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{mathtext} 
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pscyr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eskdtotal}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bf}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bf}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{8mm}{8mm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15mm}{15mm}
\parindent=1,25cm
\setlength\emergencystretch{\hsize}\hbadness=10000
\linespread{1.25}
\ESKDsectStyle{section}{\normalsize} 
\ESKDsectStyle{subsection}{\normalsize} 
\ESKDsectStyle{subsubsection}{\normalsize} 
\begin{document}
\section*{\hspace{1.25cm}Annotation} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace{22pt}Annotation}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents 
\newpage 
\section*{\hspace{1.25cm}Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace{22pt}Introduction} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean not bold?

Comment: Yes, i mean this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `eskdtext` document class appears to be built on the `extarticle` document class (which, in turn, appears to be derived from the `report` class), you could try adding the following instructions to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\mdseries}
```

Comment: If i write, i got an error ! LaTeX Error: \cftsecfont undefined and LaTeX Error: \cftsecfont undefined.

Comment: @JHZTMEUIBNA - Did you load the `tocloft` package?

Comment: Oh,sorry,i got brainlag.I wrote titlesec instead of tocloft.